# RDD map+sortByKey - Error comprehension list python

Tags: python, rdd

He Guys.

I have been receiving an error when I do something like this:

```
RDD = [(0, [1,2,3], 2),(1, [2,3,4], 4),(2, [4,5,6], 6),(3, [6,7,8], 8)]
Dados = [4,5,6]

TesteEuclediana = RDD.map(lambda x: (x[0],
                                     [math.sqrt((x[1][i][1]- Dados[i])^2) for i in range (0, int(len(Dados)))],
                                     x[2])
                         ).sortByKey()
```

I catch this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Comment: As code is now, `map(lambda x: ......, RDD)`, but `.sortByKey` doesn't fit there, so probably it's smth else.

Comment: I coded it:  TesteEuclediana = RDD.map(lambda x:(x[0],[math.sqrt((x[1][i][1]- Dados[i])^2) for i in range (0, int(len(Dados)))],x[2]))                                                  but I catch the same error.